# Problem sending more then 2 lines at time

Tags: delphi, sockets, delphi-7, winsock

I have problem with sockets.
If i send more then two lines of text using [`TClientSocket`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ScktComp.TClientSocket) then server receives one line instead of two.

Client part:

```
ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit1.Text);//Text is 'Line1'
ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit2.Text);//Text is 'Line2'
```

Server part:

```
var
s: String;
begin
s := Socket.ReceiveText;
Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
```

The Memo1 created line is 'Line1Line2'
Why?
Sorry for my english!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Delphi's SendText method, but I don't see any place that specifies a carriage return in the text.

Comment: Server receives one line instead of two lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SendText` does not send a CRLF.  If you need to send a new line, you'll have to do it explicitly:

```
ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit1.Text + #13#10);
ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit2.Text + #13#10);
```

Comment: But if i use : if Command='FormX' then begin Form.Left:=strtoint(Socket.ReceiveText);

Comment: @Robrok: Then don't use it that way: `var SL: TStringList;begin SL := TStringList.create; try SL.Text := Socket.ReceiveText; if SL.Count > 1 then begin Form.Left := StrToInt(SL[0]);  Form.Top := StrToInt(SL[1]); end; finally SL.Free; end;` should do it for you, and you can extend it however you need.

Answer (score 5):

`TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` implement TCP/IP, which is a byte stream that has no concept of message boundaries (unlike UDP, which does).  When you call `SendText()`, it just dumps the String contents as-is onto the socket.  When you call `ReceiveText()`, it returns whatever is currently in the socket buffer at that moment.  That is why you see the server receive 'Line1Line2'.  If you want to differentiate between the two lines, then you need to send a delimiter between them, such as a CRLF sequence, and then your server code needs to be updated to look for that.  Since TCP/IP is a byte stream, there is no guaranteed 1-to-1 relationship between writes and reads.  Case in point, you wrote 5 bytes followed by 5 bytes, but the server received 10 bytes all at once.  So your reading code needs to buffer everything it receives and then you can check your buffer for the data you are looking for, eg:

Client:

```
ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit1.Text + #13#10);
ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(Edit2.Text + #13#10);
```

Server:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1Connect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  Socket.Data := TMemoryStream.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1Disconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  TMemoryStream(Socket.Data).Free;
  Socket.Data := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
  RecvLen: Integer;
  StrmSize, I: Int64;
  Ptr: PByte;
  B: Byte;
  s: AnsiString;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream(Socket.Data);

  RecvLen := Socket.ReceiveLength;
  if RecvLen <= 0 then Exit;

  StrmSize := Strm.Size;
  Strm.Size := StrmSize + RecvLen;

  Ptr := PByte(Strm.Memory);
  Inc(Ptr, Strm.Position);

  RecvLen := Socket.ReceiveBuf(Ptr^, RecvLen);
  if RecvLen <= 0 then
  begin
    Strm.Size := StrmSize;
    Exit;
  end;

  Strm.Size := StrmSize + RecvLen;

  while (Strm.Size - Strm.Position) >= 2 do
  begin
    Strm.ReadBuffer(B, 1);
    if B <> 13 then Continue;

    Strm.ReadBuffer(B, 1);
    if B <> 10 then
    begin
      if B = 13 then
      begin
        Strm.Seek(-1, soCurrent);
        Continue;
      end;
    end;

    SetString(s, PAnsiChar(Strm.Memory), Strm.Position-2);

    StrmSize := Strm.Size - Strm.Position;
    if StrmSize then
    begin
      Strm.Clear;
    end else
    begin
      Ptr := PByte(Strm.Memory);
      Inc(Ptr, Strm.Position);
      Move(Ptr^, Strm.Memory^, StrmSize);
      Strm.Size := StrmSize;
      Strm.Position := 0;
    end;

    Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
  end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a CRLF or newline to Edit1.Text and Edit2.Text